# How to perform complex queries and display combined results based on multiple dropdown selections from different tables

Tags: laravel

I have a pivot table for respondents table and household_heads table, it is respondents_household table.

Now, I have dropdowns to select the respondents with infected disease with date range, vaccinated respondents, and hd_category dropdowns, I already have a function to filter the respondents based from the selected dropdowns. disease table has respondent_disease pivot table, vaccine table has respondent_vaccine pivot table and hd_category has respondent_hd_category pivot table.

I also have dropdown to filter household_heads with sdoh_category and env_hazard based from the selected dropdowns. sdoh_category has household_sdoh_category pivot table, and env_hazard table has household_env_hazard pivot table.

Now my main question is ,is it possible for example a disease from the dropdown and sdoh_category and still display the household_head_id, purok which the household belongs to and the respondent name?

here is the code to filter the respondents from disease, vaccine,ad hd_category:

```
 $infectedRespondents = Respondent::when($selectedDiseaseId, function ($query) use ($selectedDiseaseId, $startDate, $endDate) {
        $query->whereHas('diseases', function ($innerQuery) use ($selectedDiseaseId, $startDate, $endDate) {
            $innerQuery->where('disease_id', $selectedDiseaseId)
                       ->when($startDate && $endDate, function ($dateQuery) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                           $dateQuery->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
                       });
        });
    })
    ->when($selectedVaccineId, function ($query) use ($selectedVaccineId) {
        $query->whereHas('vaccines', function ($innerQuery) use ($selectedVaccineId) {
            $innerQuery->where('vaccine_id', $selectedVaccineId);
        });
    })

    ->when($hdCategoryId, function ($query) use ($hdCategoryId) {
        $query->whereHas('hd_categories', function ($innerQuery) use ($hdCategoryId) {
            $innerQuery->where('hd_category_id', $hdCategoryId);
        });
    })


    ->get();

    $infectedRespondentsWithHouseholds = $infectedRespondents->map(function ($respondent) {
        $respondent->load('household_heads.puroks');
        return $respondent;
    });
```

and the code to filter the household from sdoh_category and env_hazard :

```
$affectedHouseholds = HouseholdHead::when($envHazardId, function ($query) use ($envHazardId) {
        $query->whereHas('env_hazards', function ($innerQuery) use ($envHazardId) {
            $innerQuery->where('env_hazard_id', $envHazardId);
        });

    })


    ->when($sdohCategoryId, function ($query) use ($sdohCategoryId) {
        $query->whereHas('sdoh_categories', function ($innerQuery) use ($sdohCategoryId) {
            $innerQuery->where('sdoh_category_id', $sdohCategoryId);
        });
    })

    ->get();
```

also have different code for my views

code to display the filtered hosuehold:

```
 @foreach($affectedHouseholds as $household)
         <tr>
             <td>{{ $household->id }} </td>
             <td>{{ $household->name }}</td>
             <td>{{ $household->puroks->purok_num }}</td>
          </tr>

@endforeach
```

code to display the filtered respondent:

```
@foreach($infectedRespondentsWithHouseholds as $respondent)
     <tr>
       <td>
          @foreach($respondent->household_heads as $householdHead)
           {{ $householdHead->id }}
          @endforeach
        </td>
        <td> {{ $respondent->name }} </td>
        <td>
           @foreach($respondent->household_heads as $householdHead)
           {{ $householdHead->puroks->purok_num }}
           @endforeach
        </td>
     </tr>

@endforeach
```